# Silent MySQL install on Windows

Tags: windows, installation, mysql, silent-install

I need a way to make silent install for MySQL on Windows (without any interruption from the user). Any?

Answer (score 3):

Download the msi from [mysql.com](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/).  Then run:

```
msiexec /i mysql-5.1.44-win32.msi /passive
```

From the msiexec help:

```
/passive
    Unattended mode - progress bar only
```